# How to start MacVim 7.3 snapshot 66 WITH its toolbar

Tags: macvim

I'm using Mac OSX with Mountain Lion and I'm running MacVim 7.3 snapshot 66, I just installed it with `brew install macvim` but it doesn't starts with its toolbar and I really want it, what should i do to set it up so each time I open MacVim it starts with its toolbar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put `set guioptions+=T` in your .vimrc. Note that `set guioptions=T` clears all other gui options.

Comment: Hi Zeyu, that worked but the interface its different, those tabs are like code, not like a button, do you know how to restore them to be a button?

Comment: you can add 'e' to your `guioptions`, specifically you should put `set guioptions=Te` in your .vimrc. You may want to read [vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27guioptions%27) to find out more settings about gui.

Comment: Hey @Zeyu do you know how to activate the scrollbar too?

Comment: @Balz - check `:help guioptions` for all of the options instead of asking for them one at a time.  Also, if you use `+=` instead of `=` then you won't blow away the defaults if there are any that you like.  (You can see the defaults if you remove the `set` line and type `:set guioptions?`.)